# How to Create Deny rules for Applocker using Powershell

Tags: powershell, group-policy, gpo, applocker

When using a command such as

```
ls 'C:\Program Files\*.exe' | Get-AppLockerFileInformation | New-AppLockerPolicy -RuleType Path -User everyone -xml -optimize
```

I always see it emit "Allow" rule. How can I generate a "Deny" rule (i.e Action="Deny") in the xml that gets generated. [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460963.aspx) documentation does not say anything about having a deny option. Is XML fiddling the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the Policy rule objects that `New-AppLockerPolicy` returns before calling `Set-AppLockerPolicy`:

```
$Policy = ls 'C:\Program Files\*.exe' | Get-AppLockerFileInformation | New-AppLockerPolicy -RuleType Path -User Everyone -Optimize
foreach($RuleCollection in $Policy.RuleCollections)
{
    foreach($Rule in $RuleCollection)
    {
        $Rule.Action = 'Deny'
    }
}
Set-AppLockerPolicy -PolicyObject $Policy -Ldap "<DN to target policy>"
```

In PowerShell 4.0 and newer, you can use the `ForEach({})` extension method as well:

```
$Policy = ... | New-AppLockerPolicy
$Policy.RuleCollections.ForEach({ $_.ForEach({ $_.Action = 'Deny' }) })
Set-AppLockerPolicy -PolicyObject $Policy -Ldap ...
```

Comment: I tried this earlier but I don't think the Action property is settable. In your script try `$policy.RuleCollections[0].Action="Deny"` and then print `$policy.RuleCollections[0]`

Comment: My bad. you are right!! I did not see it was a double collection(RuleCollections & RuleCollection) and hence I was wrong.

Comment: btw. you may want to remove the -xml from your script.

Comment: @AntonyThomas Your doing it wrong - `RuleCollections` contains collections each containing rules - it's a nested array - `$policy.RuleCollections[0][0].Action` is what you want to be probing at